# Testing Sencha touch apps

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

Can anyone tell me how to test sencha touch app on mobile devices(android) physically before wrapping it up or production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Phonegap/Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) for that. At our company we use sencha build to build our sencha app, use cordova to package it as a native one, installs it in the devices (iPhone/iPad/Android Phones/Android Tablets) and then test.

For getting started on Android, you can use this [official getting started guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android).